# Nginx config to serve JavaScript application from different locations

Tags: nginx

I have a JavaScript-based web application to deploy. It ships as a JavaScript bundle (produced by webpack), an index.html file that loads this bundle, and some other static resource files, like images. I place all these files in `/usr/src/app/dist`.

The intention is that for a given request URL, nginx looks for and serves a static resource if available, otherwise it returns the index.html file so that the JavaScript application can handle the URL.

For example, if the base URL for the application is `/my-app/`, it should be that:

- `/my_app/logo.png` serves `/usr/src/app/dist/logo.png`
- `/my_app/thing/1` (no such file) serves `/usr/src/app/dist/index.html`

Or if the base URL is just `/`, then:

- `/logo.png` serves `/usr/src/app/dist/logo.png`
- `/thing/1` (no such file) serves `/usr/src/app/dist/index.html`

So far it seems simple. I have a template nginx config that looks like this. At startup, `%ROOT_PATH%` is substituted with the base URL.

```
    location %ROOT_PATH% {
        alias /usr/src/app/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ %ROOT_PATH%/index.html;
    }
```

However, I am struggling to get a simple way to do this substitution that works for *both* base path examples given, `/my_app/` and `/`.

For example, in the `location` directive, it seems that the path **must not** end with a `/`, *unless* it is exactly the string `/`. So I can't just strip the final `/` from `%ROOT_PATH%`.

If I don't strip a lone `/`, then `%ROOT_PATH%/index.html` becomes `//index.html` and nginx does not seem to like that either.

What is the best way to make this work? (I'm happy to use other types of built-in variable substitution, also, but it seems like there are shortcomings in where you are permitted to use nginx config variables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* be using a trailing slash, and it must appear in both the `location` and in the `alias`.

```
location /my_app/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /my_app/index.html
```

In the final URL, the `location` will be directly substituted with the `alias` when looking for a file in the filesystem. This will result in `/usr/src/app/dist/index.html` being loaded from storage.